# Java Jackson wrap an existing json with a root entry

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm a new user of fasterxml.jackson lib. I need an help to undestand how use that lib.
I have an array generated from a string, that I need to include into a root node, but I didn't understand how do that.

My code is:

```
 class RigaAnamnesi {
      int codRiga;
      String testo;
      boolean domandaSiNo;
      Integer sub = 0;
      String spiegazione = "Spiegazione di prova";
}
ArrayList<RigaAnamnesi> vArray = fillArray();
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(vArray);

JsonNode parsedJson = mapper.readTree(json);
         
ArrayNode outerArray = mapper.createArrayNode();
ObjectNode outerObject = mapper.createObjectNode();
outerObject.putPOJO("domande", parsedJson);
outerArray.add(outerObject);
File f = Paths.get("anamnesi.json").toFile();
mapper.writeValue(f, outerArray);
```

and my output is:

```
{
        "domande": [
            {
                "codRiga": 1,
                "testo": "Malattie del sangue e problemi di coagulazione_",
                "domandaSiNo": true,
                "sub": 0,
                "spiegazione": "Spiegazione di prova"
            },
            {
                "codRiga": 2,
                "testo": "Malattie endocrine (es.Diabete, Osteoporosi)___ ",
                "domandaSiNo": true,
                "sub": 0,
                "spiegazione": "Spiegazione di prova"
            },
            {
                "codRiga": 3,
                "testo": "Malattie cardiache e vascolari_",
                "domandaSiNo": true,
                "sub": 0,
                "spiegazione": "Spiegazione di prova,"
                },
                ...
```

but I need to include into a new root:

```
 {
    "anamnesi": {
        "domande": [
            {
                "codRiga": 1,
                "testo": "Malattie del sangue e problemi di coagulazione_",
                "domandaSiNo": true,
                "sub": 0,
                "spiegazione": ""
            },
            ....
```

Comment: You should post the entire code. Specifically, what type is "vArray" and which var are you printing?

Comment: just add another node wrapping `outerObject` in a similar way you added `domande`. As an alternative you could create POJO class with Jackson annotation and then serialize this object.

Answer (score 1):

The Jackson ObjectNode represents a JSON object `{}`. To add properties, you can either call [set(String, JsonNode)](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.html#set(java.lang.String,%20com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode)) which adds another node (object, array, or simple value) or you can call [putPOJO(String, Object)](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.html#putPOJO(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)). POJO stands for Plain Old Java Object and this call will interpret your `List<RigaAnamnesi>` class as an array of JSON objects.

To get to your desired structure, you do not need to print the array to a string first. Instead, you can create two objects and use putPOJO followed by set:

```
    List<RigaAnamnesi> vArray = ...;
    ObjectNode domande = mapper.createObjectNode();
    // use putPOJO to make sure jackson converts the POJO to JsonNodes
    domande.putPOJO("domande", vArray);

    // this is the parent we will print
    ObjectNode anamnesi = mapper.createObjectNode();
    // use set, since domande already is a JsonNode
    anamnesi.set("anamnesi", domande);

    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(anamnesi));
```